# CSS - How do I show page breaks on screen?

Tags: html, css, printing

I understand that you can currently use `page-break-before` and `page-break-after` to have the browser interpret the media as page breaks, but I was wondering if it was possible to actually have those rendered on the webpage, like a print preview inside my website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that page breaks, by their very nature only make sense in a print based settings. But, assuming you want them shown, simply apply the 'page-break-before' etc. css to a div and then, for screen only, style that div with (say) a dotted line. For print styles, just hade the dotted line and the page break will render properly...

For example:

HTML

```
<div class="myPageBreak"></div>
```

CSS (screen)

```
.myPageBreak{
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-top: 1px dotted #c5c5c5;
}
```

CSS (print)

```
.myPageBreak{
    page-break-before: always;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
}
```

This should produce a 'page break' div 20px in depth with a 1px with grey dotted line in the middle for screen. When printed, the line, the padding and the border won't display.

Comment: If I assume that I'm using a certain kind of paper, is there anyways to actually render the page breaks so there is the actual amount of space between the divs.

Comment: Also, what is actually rendering the page breaks, the print preview? or the printer?

Comment: Safest to assume that you're using A4 portrait although you have no control over what the user chooses. I'll edit my post with some styling...

Comment: In this case I actually have full control over what paper the user is using. So we are A-OK in that department :)

Comment: I am using XSL script to generate the HTML. At the moment I have: `<xsl:attribute name="style">page-break-before: always</xsl:attribute>`. I am not in a position to change that logic. So, can we apply  your styles approach to the actual page break elements themselves, as opposed to a class?